# How do you call the opencv function 'cvCreateContourTree()' in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use the opencv function cvCreateContourTree() using OpenCV 2.3.1 in the Python language. However I cannot seem to get find the exact implementation of this function. Intuitive calls such as cv.CreateContourTree() will not work.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Although cv.CreateContourTree is shown in manual, when it is called, it says there is no such function. But I found this function is used [here](http://nullege.com/codes/search/cv.CreateContourTree), i don't know how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's just called CreateContourTree - see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#index-1109

This was the top hit on Google for "python createContourTree".